# How can I find out the species of my baby turtles?

Tags: aquarium, turtles

I just received 3 baby turtles as a gift from my boyfriend and we were looking online to see what species they are. The smallest one is a darker shade of green. I saw some called [red-eared slider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-eared_slider) turtles, but my turtles don't have any sign of red ears, unless they are too small to notice. I also saw tiny red-eared slider turtles and they look like normal red-eared turtles.
Also, how do you tell a turtle's gender; and what kind of foods other than the normal turtle food, can I give them as treats?

[image: 3 baby turtles]
[image: 3 baby turtles]

Answer (score 6):

I'd be more inclined to think they're probably yellow belly sliders which are the same as far as care and size go, but they don't develop the red marks on the side of their head.

I would stick with turtle food and you can give snacks like the veggies you have in there or crickets, but the turtle food will be much better as far as nutrition is concerned.

I would do a lot of research on care, they get rather large, and need heated water and a heated basking area. They are cold blooded so the basking area, which should be heated to roughly 90 degrees, is extremely important. The very general rule for housing is 10 gallons of water per 1 inch of shell, per turtle, so right now, you're looking at roughly a 30 - 40 gallon aquarium. They grow fairly quickly as juveniles but will slow down, but for 3 adults you honestly are in the territory of needing a pond, they get commonly 10 - 12in in length.

Comment: They are loners, only like meetings to make babys. So you can not add up the rule of Jestep for three turtles three times...